# How to verify controller actions are defined for all routes in a rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, url-routing

Is there a way to verify that all controller actions, as defined in `config/routes.rb` and exposed by `rake routes`, actually correspond to an existing controller action?

For example, suppose we have the following routes file:

```
Application.routes.draw do
  resources :foobar
end
```

And the following controller:

```
class FoobarsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # ...
  end

  def show
    # ...
  end
end
```

I'd like to have some way of auto-detecting that the `create`, `new`, `edit`, `update` and `destroy` actions (as implicitly defined by the routes) are not mapped to a valid controller action - so that I can fix the `routes.rb` file:

```
Application.routes.draw do
  resources :foobar, only: [:index, :show]
end
```

An "integrity check" of the routes, if you will.

**Such a check wouldn't necessarily need to be perfect**; I could easily verify any false positives manually. (Although a "perfect" check would be ideal, as it could be included in the test suite!)

My motivation here is to prevent `AbstractController::ActionNotFound` exceptions from being raised by dodgy API requests, as additional routes were inadvertently defined (in a large application).

Comment: You could perhaps create a routing test/spec that iterates through `Rails.application.routes` and tests each route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Huge credit to the other answers - please check them out below. But this is what I've ended up using on multiple projects over the past couple of years, and it's served me well. So I'm self-marking this as the accepted answer for visibility.

I placed the following in `spec/routes/integrity_check_spec.rb`:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'Integrity Check of Routes', order: :defined do # rubocop:disable RSpec/DescribeClass
  Rails.application.routes.routes.sort_by { |r| r.defaults[:controller].to_s }.each do |route|
    controller, action = route.defaults.slice(:controller, :action).values

    # Some routes may have the controller assigned as a dynamic segment
    # We need to skip them since we can't really test them in this way
    next if controller.nil?

    # Skip the built in Rails 5 active_storage routes
    next if controller.split('/').first == 'active_storage'

    # Skip built in Rails 6 action_mailbox routes
    next if controller == 'rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails'

    ctrl_name = "#{controller.sub('\/', '::')}_controller".camelcase
    ctrl_klass = ctrl_name.safe_constantize

    it "#{ctrl_name} is defined and has corresponding action: #{action}, for #{route.name || '(no route name)'}" do
      expect(ctrl_klass).to be_present
      expect(ctrl_klass.new).to respond_to(action)
    end
  end
end
```

Caveats:

- This is only a basic check for "does the controller action exist?". It does not consider parameters, format, subdomains, or any other route constraints. However, in my experience, that's good enough for the vast majority of scenarios.
- This test only ensures that defined routes map to valid controller actions, *not* the converse. So it's still possible to have "dead code" in controllers, without a test failing. I haven't attempted to address that problem here.
- It's *possible* for a route to have [**no controller action** and still be **valid**](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-by-default-convention-over-configuration-in-action)!! This test can fail in such scenarios! As a workaround, you could - for example - define empty methods in the controller, instead of relying on the "magic" rails default behaviour. But the key takeaway here is: **be careful** when removing "dead" routes; you cannot immediately assume that a failing test here means the route is invalid.

Answer (score 9):

I got curious, and the following is my attempt. It's still not accurate because it does not yet match proper `format`. Also, some routes have constraints; my code doesn't yet consider.

**`rails console`**:

```
todo_skipped_routes = []
valid_routes = []
invalid_routes = []

Rails.application.routes.routes.each do |route|
  controller_route_name = route.defaults[:controller]
  action_route_name = route.defaults[:action]

  if controller_route_name.blank? || action_route_name.blank?
    todo_skipped_routes << route
    next
  end

  # TODO: maybe Rails already has a "proper" way / method to constantize this
  # copied over @max answer, because I forgot to consider namespacing
  controller_class = "#{controller_route_name.sub('\/', '::')}_controller".camelcase.safe_constantize

  is_route_valid = !controller_class.nil? && controller_class.instance_methods(false).include?(action_route_name.to_sym)

  # TODO: check also if "format" matches / gonna be "responded to" properly by the controller-action
  #   check also "lambda" constraints, and `request.SOMEMETHOD` constraints (i.e. `subdomain`, `remote_ip`,  `host`, ...)

  if is_route_valid
    valid_routes << route
  else
    invalid_routes << route
  end
end

puts valid_routes
puts invalid_routes

# puts "friendlier" version
pp invalid_routes.map(&:defaults)
# => [
#  {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"somenonexistingaction"},
#  {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"criate"},
#  {:controller=>"yoosers", :action=>"create"},
# ]
```

*I am also interested to know other answers, or if there is a proper way to do this. Also, if anyone knows an improvement over my code, please let me know. Thanks :)*

Comment: Could tidy this up a little using [partition](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/partition). This would skip needing to assign two of the three blank arrays and the if / else at the end of the loop. Nice answer though, +1 :)

Comment: @SRack ohhh I haven't heard of `partition`. Nice! Thanks! :) Although, looking at partition, I'm not sure if it's readable enough immediately, because it's gonna look like this, no? https://repl.it/repls/BriefKaleidoscopicVoxels
In particular, if I want to get the "valid" routes, I'll have to access `[0]` of the array, which kinda feel not-that-readable to me, or maybe that's just me (because I'm not used to this `partition`). I'm open-minded though, and open to discussion, and maybe I can change my approach :) But thanks for the response!!

Comment: Nice answer! I was curious too.

Comment: @Pavan thanks!! Although, I'm sure my answer is still half-correct because of `constraints`, `format`, and `subdomain` (as an example), especially `format` because the `respond_to` is inside the controller-action itself! And I got stuck trying to find a way, without "evaluating" / running and testing controller-action if it would in fact call `respond_to :someformat` correctly. hahaha! Some routes also have "lambda" constraints, and it's kinda difficult to evaluate and match properly, but if I get time, maybe I can further test this out :)

Comment: This is an interesting starting point, but it could certainly do with some tweaking... From my initial test run, the output from those `puts` isn't any use and it died when encountering a non-existent controller. (Which is actually a very useful find!) Perhaps logging the `controller_class` and `action_name` would be simplest/most useful...

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario - it's often used as `valid_routes, invalid_routes = Rails.application.routes.routes.partition do |route|...`. That way you get your truthy and falsy results assigned on return.

Comment: @TomLord ahh true, you're right! I failed to add a rescue block there if `constantize` failed! I'll update my code. thanks! :)

Comment: @SRack ahh you're perfectly right! I forgot that you can do this like that. I'll update my code. thanks! :)

Comment: Well, atleast this a good starting point not just for the OP, for everyone who wants to perform the same. Great effort! I still think there could be a Rails inbuilt helper(which we are not aware of)which can perform such check. Just saying..

Comment: @Pavan thanks! Yeah I hope so too that there already is a built-in Rails way! :)

Comment: @SRack I ran again my code using `partition`, but my `invalid_routes` array were also being populated with the `route` of which `next` has been called. i.e. say `[1,2,3].partition{|x| next if x == 2; true }` returns `=> [[1, 3], [2]]`: I've wanted to isolate `x` because I wanted to instead put x == 2 into `todo_skipped_routes` array, but from the result value, `2` is still added to the second-element of the array-partition. And so I had to revert back to my manual-array `<<` element-adding-code. Although, I'm gonna be using `partition` now in the future as necessary :)

Answer (score 3):

This builds on Jay-Ar Polidario's answer:

```
require 'test_helper'

class RoutesTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  Rails.application.routes.routes.each do |route|
    controller, action = route.defaults.slice(:controller, :action).values
    # Some routes may have the controller assigned as a dynamic segment
    # We need to skip them since we can't really test them in this way
    next if controller.nil?
    # Skip the built in Rails 5 active_storage routes
    next if 'active_storage' == controller.split('/').first 
    # Naive attempt to resolve the controller constant from the name
    # Replacing / with :: is for namespaces
    ctrl_name = "#{controller.sub('\/', '::')}_controller".camelcase
    ctrl = ctrl_name.safe_constantize
    # tagging SecureRandom.uuid on the end is a hack to ensure that each
    # test name is unique
    test "#{ctrl_name} controller exists - #{SecureRandom.uuid}" do
      assert ctrl, "Controller #{ctrl_name} is not defined for #{route.name}"
    end
    test "#{controller} has the action #{action} - #{SecureRandom.uuid}" do
      assert ctrl.respond_to?(action),
        "#{ctrl_name} does not have the action '#{action}' - #{route.name}"
    end if ctrl
  end
end
```

However I would question if its actually usable for anything beyond the most trivial examples.

Comment: *"I would question if its actually usable for anything beyond the most trivial examples"* -- I'll try this out some complex applications to see how reliable it is for me... But as I said originally, even if there are some false positives, these can be verified manually! (And perhaps added to some `false_positives` list inside the spec?)

Comment: I don't really think you can programatically generate tests for  any real routing. The number of possible permutations of methods, formats, constraints etc is enormous.

Comment: For now, I'm only focusing on whether the controller action exists. I'm not looking at parameters, format, subdomains, etc. I suspect this covers the vast majority of extra routes, without needing to dive too deep into corner cases.